# FindFirstFile not working as expected

Tags: c, winapi

FindFirstFile win32 function failing. please resolve the issue. Thanks

```
#include<Windows.h>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


#define ValidDir(data) strcmp(data.cFileName,".")&&strcmp(data.cFileName,"..")

void MergeDir(char *path)
{

 WIN32_FIND_DATA data={0};
 HANDLE h;
 int nFiles,i=0;
 char temp[MAX_PATH];
 char **files = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10000);
 sprintf(temp,"%s*.*",path);//path = c:\windows name = *.*
 h = FindFirstFile(temp,&data);//temp = c:\windows\*.*
    /Invalid handle is being returned.....    
 if(h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){  //Check whether we got valid handle or not 
  i = 0;
  do{
   if(ValidDir(data)){//Checks whether the Dir is . or ..
    files[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_PATH);
    sprintf(files[i++],"%s%s",path,data.cFileName); 
   }
  }while(FindNextFile(h,&data));
  nFiles = --i;
  FindClose(h);

  for(i = 0; nFiles > 0 && i < nFiles-1; i++){
   printf("\n%s\n%s\n----------------",files[i],files[i+1]);
  }
 }

}
int main()
{
    //list all files in the following directory
 MergeDir("D:\\IIIT\\Sem2\\IRE\\Processed\\");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why it is failing, any error messages, etc...

Comment: If "Invalid handle is being returned" is your issue, call GetLastError() and you will know why it failed.

Comment: A quick check using "C:\\" as the initial directory seems to work. Are you sure you don't have a typo in the string you've given in main? I'd change it to just "C:\\" or "D:\\" for an initial test. I would note that your comment "temp=c:\windows\*.*" seems to disagree with the code in `main`...

Comment: I hope it's not a commercial product you're developing.  This code's gonna crash a lot.

Comment: not commcercial IIIT is Indian Institute of IT; have added homework tag

Comment: Actually it is your code that is failing, FindFirstFile is working correctly.

Comment: That `sprintf` doesn't look too good; better hope that the length of the path plus the length of the file isn't greater than 260....

Comment: At least his command to the fellow programmers came preceeded with a "please".  Geez...

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was resolved my project is set to UNICODE and I am passing a asci string so FindFirstFile is failing. THanks to your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues with ascii to unicode then you can use another windows API to convert before you pass into the function. This worked perfectly in my C application when I was trying to use FindFirstFile with an ascii path (code simplified for explanation):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

char searchName[_MAX_PATH];
char resultName[_MAX_PATH];
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind;
WCHAR wSearchName[_MAX_PATH];

// the path is made from inputs, looks like "path\to\folder\*.extension"
// the path is stored in searchName

// encode string for search
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, searchName, _MAX_PATH, wSearchName, _MAX_PATH);

hFind = FindFirstFile(wSearchName, &FindFileData);
while (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    //convert result name back to ascii and do something with it
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, FindFileData.cFileName, _MAX_PATH, resultName, _MAX_PATH, NULL, NULL);
    // do something with result

    // keep moving to next files
    if (!FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData))
    {
        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't convert from ASCII to Unicode. ASCII is a subset of Unicode (the code points 0-127 have identical meanings in both standards), so the conversion is trivial. You probably mean conversion from multi-byte representation to wide character representation of strings.

Answer (score 0):

you are using char* as a parameter. First you need to convert it to wide char than go for FindFirstFile and FindNextFile Function.

```
void MergeFile(char * s_Path){

     wchar_t *w_Path = (wchar_t *)malloc(strlen(s_Path) * sizeof(wchar_t));

     mbstowcs(w_Path,s_Path,strlen(s_Path) + 1);

     WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;

     LPCWSTR m_Path = w_Path;

     memset(&fd,0,sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

     HANDLE hfile = FindFirstFile(m_Path,&fd);

     while(hfile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
     {

        if(fd.dwFileAttributes != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {

           printf("\n %S",fd.cFileName);

        }

        if(FindNextFile(hfile,&fd)==false) break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, anyone that uses preprocessor definitions for API calls and not their direct notation:

`#define FindFirstFile FindFirstFileA/W`

Should use the preprocessor typedef as a parameter

`typedef LPCTSTR LPC(W)STR`

`TCHAR`'s are invoked in the WINAPI for a reason people! If you are writing code to be portable in anyone's IDE (pasting code on github for example). Use `TCHAR`'s, `LPCTSTR` will work with both `FindFirstFileA/W`.

Or simply use the explicit API notation, `FindFirstFileW` (in this circumstance as you're expecting system file names, and if they have unicode characters, and the default system charset isn't set to the correct code base, you will get "junk/garbage" characters in your output buffer).

Another side note, if you're working with System file or System Paths, always use `Unicode` because `ANSI` relies directly on the code base, and if you're on an arabic system, the file path will be messed up in `ANSI`.